# select.options is undefined when trying to loop through ListBoxFor()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

Im getting this error and i dont understand why. Please help.
What Im trying to do is loop through all the options on a multiselectlist.

HTML/Razor

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedUsersIdsArray, new MultiSelectList(Model.Users, "ID", "NAME"), new { id = "Select", multiple = "multiple" })
```

JavaScript

```
var filterFuncionarios = [];
    @foreach (var f in Model.Funcionarios)
    {
        @:filterFuncionarios.push({ Id: "@f.ID"})
    }
    var selecionados = $('#usersSelectDropdown')[0].options;
    
    function filtraListDeFuncionarios() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selecionados.length; i++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < filterFuncionarios.length; i++) {
                if (selecionados[i].value == filterFuncionarios[k].Id) {
                    selecionados[i].selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the exact code im running.

Error
Uncaught TypeError: selecionados[i] is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already reading the `options` array here:

```
var select = $('#Select')[0].options;
```

Which you loop over:

```
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
```

But then you try to read another `options` property on that same array:

```
if (select.options[i].value == filterFuncionarios[k].Id) {
    select.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Overall you've confused yourself with poor variable names.  The initial variable is called "select" but it *isn't* a "select".  It's an array of options.  So call it that:

```
var options = $('#Select')[0].options;
```

Then looping over it is more intuitive:

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
```

And accessing each option is clear:

```
if (options[i].value == filterFuncionarios[k].Id) {
    options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Comment: I did this and still gives me options[i] is undefined.. Any ideas?

Comment: @JuniorDevCaput: Can you update the question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  Since we're just talking about client-side code, focus on the resulting markup generated by the server-side code and you can create a runnable code snippet in the question to demonstrate.

Comment: @JuniorDevCaput: I just noticed a typo on your code.  In your second loop you are incrementing `i` instead of `k`.  If you `console.log` the value of `i` you'll see that it exceeds the length of `options` causing the error.  Change the second loop to increment `k` and [the code works](https://jsfiddle.net/0rvu4wps/).

Comment: Omg you'r right. Thank you! Although i don't have the error now it still isn't selecting the options in the list.. probably this is not the way to go. Thanks for your help and I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

You've received options in select definition,

var select = $('#Select')[0].**options**;

then you trying to access options in for

select.options[i].selected = true; will be equal to  $('#Select')[0].options.options;

I suggest you to remove .options from $('#Select')